# Recursive Notifications

Tags: ios, ipad, nsnotificationcenter

My application is IOS application.
I have a scenario typical to the calendar iPad application, when  the user goto to a date from a view, each views update itself and notify others. The problem is that notifications between views never ends.

I am using the NSNotificationCenter

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SelectedDateChangedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
```

I would like to explore some ideas of how effectively implement this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: It's considered good etiquette on SO to accept answers.  You should go back and accept some of the answers to your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two ways of updating each of your views.  The first way is when the user updates it and the second way when it gets updated by a different view.  The first way sends notifications to the other views and the second way does not.  From an implementation standpoint, the first way would just be a wrapper around the second way which first notifies the other views.